# Accessing Directive scope with in HTML element event handler

Tags: angular, closures, angular6

I created a `Directive` to use an element as 'dropzone` with native HTML Drag & Drop

## Directive source

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter, ViewChild } 
from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Directive({
    selector: '[app-drop-zone]'
})
export class DropzoneDirective implements OnInit {    
    @Output('outbound-listener') outBoundListener = new EventEmitter();    

    constructor(private e: ElementRef) {        
        e.nativeElement.ondrop = this.drop;
        e.nativeElement.ondragover = this.dragOver;
        e.nativeElement.ondragenter = this.dragEnter;
        e.nativeElement.ondragleave = this.dragLeave;            
    }

    ngOnInit(): void { }

    private drop(event: any){ 

        let files: File[] = []; // temprary cache for dropped files

        if (event.stopPropagation) {
           event.stopPropagation(); // Stops some browsers from redirecting.
        }

        event.currentTarget.classList.remove('over');    // remove the 
        dotted background, once user release the content (drop-end)

       // process dropped items
       if(event.dataTransfer.items){
       for(let i = 0; i< event.dataTransfer.items.length; i++){
           if(event.dataTransfer.items[i].kind == "file"){
               files.push(event.dataTransfer.items[i].getAsFile());
           }
       }

       if(files.length > 0){
           this.outBoundListener.emit({ type: 
           environment.component_events.INIT_FILE_UPLOAD, data: files});              
       }
    }
    return false;
 }

 private dragOver(e){
      if(e.preventDefault)
          e.preventDefault();    

      e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
      return false;
 }

 private dragEnter(event: any) {     
    event.currentTarget.classList.add('over');    
 }

 private dragLeave(event: any) {    
    event.currentTarget.classList.remove('over');    
 }
}
```

** Please ignore code formatting astheitcs :-(

*Problem* here is , in method 'drop', I want to access Directive Class prop `outBoundListener` which is an `EventEmitter` But I am unable call it via `this`

Any help regarding this will be appreciated..

Comment: That should be accessible using `this.outBoundListener`.

Comment: ^ this is actually my problem here. It isn't accessible, `this` refers to the owner (callee) here

Comment: What's strange about that is that "JS closure standards" don't come into play here. That would be the case if you used the `function drop` syntax, but the way you declared it, `this` should absolutely point to your object, not the function. What is the specific error you get?

Comment: simply "can not read property `outboundListener` of `undefined` ".

Comment: ^ updated my submission. What'd be the fix to this scenario?

Comment: @CobusKruger this is typescript sir. it compiles to `function drop`.

Comment: Yes, that's what it compiles to, but the semantics are different. As per the explanation on https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html, arrow functions don't capture `this`. Anyway, I realised what your problem is and will post a solution soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have absolutely should work *when called from TypeScript code*, as TypeScript/ES6 `this` semantics are a little different for arrow functions. You can read more about that [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html), where there is an entire section dedicated to the hot mess that is `this`.

The problem here is not that `this` refers to the owner or callee, but to the DOM element. You can verify this by calling `console.log(this)` at the top of your `drop` function.

The reason things are going wonky, is because this function is not called from ES6 or TypeScript code, but from the DOM event handlers. To force it to preserve `this`, you can use the `bind` function.

```
constructor(private e: ElementRef) {        
    e.nativeElement.ondrop = this.drop.bind(this);
    e.nativeElement.ondragover = this.dragOver.bind(this);
    e.nativeElement.ondragenter = this.dragEnter.bind(this);
    e.nativeElement.ondragleave = this.dragLeave.bind(this);
}
```

Notice that `this` is your object instance and you are now forcing that to be the case by creating a new function using the supplied `this` value, as per [the MDN explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

The alternative would be to use an arrow function inline.

```
constructor(private e: ElementRef) {        
    e.nativeElement.ondrop = event => this.drop(event);
    e.nativeElement.ondragover = event => this.dragOver(event);
    e.nativeElement.ondragenter = event => this.dragEnter(event);
    e.nativeElement.ondragleave = event => this.dragLeave(event); 
}
```

Here it works, because the arrow function preserves `this`, as mentioned before.